# Getting MemoryError from DataFrame.sortlevel in pandas

Tags: pandas

I'm trying to run sortlevel(0,0) on a `DataFrame` with a MultiIndex (3 levels) and a size of about 900'000x4.

```
>>>data.as_matrix().shape
(899262, 4)
>>>data.sortlevel(0,0) #<--- throws MemoryError almost instantaneous
```

I'm running Windows Vista (not willingly) and as I understand it a process can only allocate about 2GB of RAM, but I can't see how the .sortlevel can use that amount of RAM really? What algorithm is used for the sorting? Is there any walkarounds to sort it in the same way?

**Edit** Did only test it in ipython by old habit.

Comment: Looks like an issue. Is data a slice from a bigger set of data? What do you get if you do data.reset_index().sort(<label of index level_0>)?

Comment: No it shouldn't be a slice. data.reset_index().sort('slot') seems to work.

Comment: Could you post an issue on Github https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues? Include os, pandas version and code to reproduce issue.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce it for some reason, a generated dataframe which looks essentially the same works without hassle.

Comment: Now I get MemoryError just before when appending 4 dataframes, I think I'll have to look into this closer.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be an issue with using `run filename.py` in *ipython*, it for some reason used alot more RAM then the ordinary *python* from the command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

There are some places where pandas is not as careful as it could be about memory usage when it comes to MultiIndex-- if you do find a case that reproduces the issue please do post it on the issue tracker.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same MemoryError problem sorting large DataFrames when the module was run from IPython.

If you have a 64 bit processor, operating system and more than 2GB of RAM another solution is to run 64 bit Python, you can get a prepackaged 64 bit version of Python like [Anaconda Community Edition](https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda) or [get the unofficial 64 binaries](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pandas)